# Case Insensitive Associative Array Keys

Tags: arrays, lua, case

I'm working with an associative array/table in Lua. I'd like to compare a case insensitive user input to the case sensitive keys of the table.

Ex:

```
table = { ["HellO"] = "world" }
user_input = "hello"
table_entry = table[user_input]
```

If possible I'd like something like the above example to end with "world" stored in table_entry.

However, I'd really like to avoid looping through the entire table (which will be large) and comparing a string.lower(key) to a string.lower(user_input).

Also, I don't have control over the creation of the table so I can't create it with only lowercase/uppercase keys.

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps create another table which maps the lowercase version of the key to the (potentially 0, 1, or more) mixed-case keys in the original table. Then lowercase the user input and look it up in the new table.

Comment: this is probably your best bet. you'll unfortunately have to loop the table once, but then you'll get the fast lookups you need from there.

Answer (score 3):

You don't say what you intend to do about collisions (the original table contains both `'hello'` and `'Hello'`, with different values.

You don't say if the original table will be updated or if it is fixed.   If it is to be updated and you cannot intercept updates, you are screwed, as you never know what the truth is going to be.

Some ideas:

- If the original table is never going to be updated, then you can make a 'shadow' table that uses the keys of the original smashed to lower case:

  ```
  shadow = { }
  for k, v in pairs(original) do shadow[k:lower()] = v end
  ```

  Look up using `shadow[userkey:lower()]`.
- If the original table is going to be updated, but most keys will hit, you can build a case mapping that gives the equivalent mixed case to any lower case:

  ```
  mixed = { }
  for k in pairs(original) do mixed[k:lower()] = k end
  ```

  Look up using `original[mixed[userkey:lower()]]` (only when `mixed[...]` is not nil).

  In this scenario if you get a good key you are set even if the value has changed.  But if you get a missing key, you will have to do something expensive.  (Unless you can intercept updates.)

If the original table is out of your control *and* you have no way to detect when it is updated, you are well and truly screwed.  In this scenario I would try to interpolate an empty table and use the `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods to record updates.  That will add overhead but will still be cheaper than a linear search.

Comment: He does specify "string.lower(key) to a string.lower(user_input as a possible solution" so the shadow table would be a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have control over the creation of the table so I can't create it with only lowercase/uppercase keys.

Then you'll have to traverse it at least once. It's a hashtable; there's no way to make different strings hash to the same value (without altering Lua's core).

If memory is not an issue, you can do one traversal to create a new lookup table. If memory is an issue, you'll have to iterate through the entire table every time.

Or find some way of getting control over the creation of that table. :)